# Cauchy can't be applied on this inequality for this condition of a, b, c

Tags: inequality, quadratics, substitution, symmetric-polynomials

Given three numbers $a,b,c$ satisfy $0\le a,b,c\le 2$ and $a+b+c=3$.

Prove that $a^2+b^2+c^2\le \frac{1}{ab+bc+ca}+\frac{9}{2}$.

**Attempt:**

By trial and error, I know that the equality does **not** hold for $a=b=c=1$. However, the equality holds for all permutations of $(0;1;2)$. Because if the problem can be solved by Cauchy inequality, then the equality will usually (if not always) hold if $a=b=c$. My attempt is below:

This inequality is true:

$a^2+b^2+c^2\le \frac{1}{ab+bc+ca}+\frac{9}{2}$

$\Leftrightarrow \left(a+b+c\right)^2-2ab-2bc-2ca\le \frac{1}{ab+bc+ca}+\frac{9}{2}$

$\Leftrightarrow 3^2-\frac{9}{2}\le \frac{2\left(ab+bc+ca\right)^2+1}{ab+bc+ca}$ 
(after this I'll put $x=ab+bc+ca$)

$\Leftrightarrow 4.5\le \frac{2x^2+1}{x} \Leftrightarrow 2x^2+1 \ge 4.5x$

$\Leftrightarrow 2x^2-4.5x+1\ge 0$ $\Leftrightarrow x\le 0.25$ or $x\ge2$.

$\Leftrightarrow ab+bc+ca \le0.25$ or $ab+bc+ca\ge 2$.

At this point I'm stuck, is this the right way to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way is right.

You need only to end it:

Let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, $1\leq a\leq2$ and $$ab+ac+bc\geq a(b+c)=a(3-a)=2+(2-a)(a-1)\geq2.$$

Comment: Well, I do think that these types of inequalities requires you to assume that numbers a, b, c are in descending order, but I haven't thought of this so thanks anyway.